# How to remove dots in the site description?

Tags: seo

I am working on the SEO of my project.

When I search for my site in the search engine,

I see the site description there, but it has a dot.

This dot hurts my SEO.

https://prnt.sc/cUaX1FL_bEb7

That's my meta tag

https://prnt.sc/JNJstBOos0Br

There are no dots in the code at all.

I don't have this problem in the code, tell me how to solve it

Comment: By "dot" you mean "period at the end of a sentence."  How is that hurting your SEO?

Comment: Google's algorithm often decides to add a period to the end of meta description, in my experience. It doesn't usually affect SEO, so I'd ask the same question as Stephen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google prepares meta descriptions based on user experiences. These meta descriptions do not have to be the meta descriptions you write. We cannot interfere with this.

If Google wants, it can put the same meta description you wrote or put any sentence from the article in the meta description within the website. Unfortunately, it is not possible for us to intervene in this.

As for the period, Google puts a period at the end of each meta description if the sentence is over and an ellipsis if it is not. You can see this by searching for any website in Google as site:example.com.

Finally, this does not cause any SEO problems.

Edit: As Reza Ataei says "New Google's meta description length is up to 920 pixels, which might allow for up to 158 characters. On mobile devices, the max limit is about 680 pixels and 120 characters." The punctuation at the end of meta descriptions varies accordingly.

Comment: New Google's meta description length is up to 920 pixels, which might allow for up to 158 characters. On mobile devices, the max limit is about 680 pixels and 120 characters.